# Bound probability of $P(|X|<t)$ with bounds on $P(X<t)$ and $P(X>-t)$.

Tags: probability

Given a random variable $X$, suppose we know $P(X<t)\ge a$ and $P(X>-t)\ge a$.

According to *High Dimensional Probability for Data Science*, (available [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf), screenshot at the bottom) page 110, we should be able to get the same bound on $P(|X|<t)$. How is this possible? I would write simply

$$P(|X|<t)=1-P(|X|>t)=1-(P(X>t)+P(X<-t))\ge 2-2a$$

So how do we get the requested bound?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text only says a "similar bound," not "the same bound."

Also in your last step you should have
$$1 - (P(X>t) + P(X<-t)) = 1 - (1- a + 1 - a) = 2a - 1.$$

With $a = 1-2e^{-ct^2}$, we have $2a-1 = 1-4e^{-ct^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A more intuitive way of thinking is to add the tail bounds:

- We have $\Pr[f(X) > M+t] \le 2\exp(-ct^2)$.
- Repeating the argument for $-f$, we have $\Pr[f(X) < M-t] \le 2\exp(-ct^2)$.
- Adding these together, we have $$\Pr[f(X) > M+t \text{ or } f(X) < M-t] \le 4\exp(-ct^2).$$

Now we can finish by taking the complement, turning the tail bound into a concentration inequality: $$\Pr[|f(X)-M| \le t] \ge 1 - 4\exp(-ct^2).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the bound that we need on $P(|f(X)-M|\le t)$ is $1-2\exp(-ct^2)$, to apply one of the defining properties of subgaussian distributions (equation 2.14 in the book).

Comment: Well, that bound just cannot be deduced from the information we have. It's $1 - 4\exp(-ct^2)$ or nothing. (However, I think that definition is unnecessarily strict about the constant in front; the $c$ in the exponent affects the result much more than a change from $2$ to $4$.) Also, it's possible that there is a mistake in the calculation for $\Pr[f(X) > M+t]$, and that the bound there should simply be $\exp(-ct^2)$. I do not see a reason for the $2$ to be there. This would give the correct final answer.